# Is it possible to extract text from a Wagtail streamfield block and strip formatting

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to extract the text from a Wagtail PostPage, and display that text in a Django page outside of Wagtail.

The relevant part of my PostPage model is:

```
body = StreamField([
    ('heading', blocks.CharBlock()),
    ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
    ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
], blank=True)
```

In my template, I am displaying the posts that get passed like so:

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
    <a class="blog-post-link" href="{% pageurl blog %}">{{ blog.title}}</a>
    {{ blog.body|truncatewords_html:10 }}
    <a href="{% pageurl blog %}">Read More</a>
{% endfor %}
```

This works, but the text that returns has all the formatting that was applied in the DraftTail editor.

Is there any way to pull just the text and pass it to the template from the wagtail side, or would the text have to be reformatted in the template using custom template tags or something else?

Extra question: I was concerned about `blog.body` pulling in the heading or the image defined in the streamfield, but so far it seems to jump to the first paragraph when looking for what to display. This is good, but is there a way to guarantee this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

For this display, I don't think there is a distinction between pages routed by wagtail's page router vs routed by a specific Django page. I think what you may want to do is use Wagtail's `richtext` filter and then truncate - more or less as you are doing with `{% pageurl blog %}`.

If you are concerned about getting headings and images in this other context, is it possible to create a new field for use on this display? If you already have a bunch of blog posts, you might need to write a script to fill in the text once you have added the field. But in that script it should be easier to skip the tags you don't want. AND then you can allow authors to edit the summary/blurb field so it makes better sense in the 10 word summary.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want plain text, you can use the streamfield `render_as_block()` method then parse the html with BeautifulSoup to grab the inner text and clean out any unwanted text from there.

I use this function to do some NLP on StreamField corpus:

```
import re
from html import unescape

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_streamfield_text(
    streamfield, 
    strip_newlines=True, 
    strip_punctuation=True, 
    lowercase=False,
    strip_tags=['style', 'script', 'code']
    ):
    
    html = streamfield.render_as_block()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(html), "html.parser")

    # strip unwanted tags tags (e.g. ['code', 'script', 'style'])
    # <style> & <script> by default
    if strip_tags:
        for script in soup(strip_tags):
            script.extract()

    inner_text = ' '.join(soup.findAll(text=True))

    # replace &nbsp; with space
    inner_text = inner_text.replace('\xa0',' ')

    # replace & with and
    inner_text = inner_text.replace(' & ',' and ')

    # strip font awesome text
    inner_text = re.sub(r'\bfa-[^ ]*', '', inner_text)

    if strip_newlines:
        inner_text = re.sub(r'([\n]+.?)+', ' ', inner_text)

    if strip_punctuation:
        # replace xx/yy with xx yy, leave fractions (1/2)
        inner_text = re.sub(r'(?<=\D)/(?=\D)', ' ', inner_text)
        # strip full stops, leave decimal points and point separators
        inner_text = re.sub(r'\.(?=\s)', '', inner_text)
        punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~“”‘’–«»‹›¿¡'
        inner_text = inner_text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuation))

    if lowercase:
        inner_text = inner_text.lower()

    # strip excess whitespace
    inner_text = re.sub(r' +', ' ', inner_text).strip()

    return inner_text
```

Set the parameters to true/false as needed.

I don't do this in rendering though, too much overhead. I fire it off in an after edit/create hook and save the result to a read-only field.